# Some users can not request the new password mail

Tags: email, password-recovery, magento-1.9.3.8

I'm not able to figure out, why some users can not request the "Forgot Password E-Mails", so Magento can not send them to the users.
Magento shows message like "the mail isn't a correct one".
Tested in firefox, chrome but sometimes it works sometimes not.

have anyone idea about this problem?

> frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/forgotpassword.phtml